# Addition & Subtraction multiple column from multiple TABLES POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql

- table1(sum(col_claim)=100)
- table2(sum(col_claim)=50)
- table3(sum(col_release)=75)
- table4(sum(col_release_two)=25)

```
select total_claim-total_release;
```

Result = (100+50) - (75+25) = 50

Comment: Most people prefer sample data as [tabular data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just inline the subqueries and do the arithmetic:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT SUM(col_claim) FROM table1) +
    (SELECT SUM(col_claim) FROM table2) -
    (SELECT SUM(col_release) FROM table3) -
    (SELECT SUM(col_release_two) FROM table4) AS result;
```